# Ajax call should not wait for response

Tags: ajax

I am using ajax call in my classic asp application to execute a stored procedure.
But I don't want to wait until the stored procedure is running (Stored procedure taking approx 5-10 minutes to complete.).
The Ajax have to invoke the stored procedure and need to come back immediately.
I want Ajax call should not wait for response.

Here is my code snippet:

```
1)  $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "runstoredprocedure.asp",  
});    
2)  setInterval(function(){  jQuery("#list").trigger("reloadGrid"); },10000);
```

These are the two ajax calls I am using. the first one is running approxmately 5-7 min. Second one is not firing until first one completes. But immediately i need to call the second ajax call.

Can anyone help me on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is by default asynchronous ( and it's the default option in all the javascript libraries ). For example, in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

You have a success, which takes a callback. When your action will finish, the callback will be called. jQuery will return immediately.

Comment: I am usingthe falowing  $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "p...te.asp",  
}); But I found using fire bug this ajax call is running for long timt.

Comment: @vissu pepala,Edit your question to add the code snippet you're using. It's not visible from the comment.

Comment: I have Edited. @Senthess, can you able see now?

Comment: @vissu pepala,Why don't you have a success callback? Even if an empty one.

Comment: Is there a way to use jQuery's ajax without it having to wait for the success or error callback?

Answer (score 5):

javascript fires off the request as part of a different thread and any code following your ajax call will be immediately executed. Having said that one misconception about JS async :

```
People take for granted that because it’s asynchronous, it’s a thread. They are partially right. There must be a thread created by the browser to keep the javascript running while it makes a request to the server. It’s internal and you don’t have access to that thread. But, the callback function called when the server responds to the ajax request is not in a thread.

I’ll explain clearer. If javascript runs some code that takes 5 seconds to execute and an ajax response arrives at 2 seconds, it will take 3 seconds before it will be executed (before the callback function is called). That’s because javascript itself doesn’t create a thread to execute the ajax response from the server and simply waits that all executions are terminated before starting a new one.

So if you’re running a lot of ajax requests simultaneously, you might get some weird behavior because they will all wait one on another before executing themselves.
```

The last statement is relevant to your cause.

Excerpt from the blog: http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/06/04/ajax-and-javascript-dont-use-threads/

Interesting read: http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/06/12/ajax-javascript-and-threads-the-final-truth/